# How do I extract a path from html with sed?

Tags: regex, replace, sed, path, extract

This has been driving me crazy. I'm trying to extract a path from some html using sed and som regex. my raw text is a file, sample.txt which looks like this:

```
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icon/file.ico" alt="[FILE]"></td><td><a href="/namespace/media/cloud-sync.xml">cloud&#x2d;sync&#x2e;xml</a></td><td align="right">Sat,&nbsp;29&nbsp;Mar&nbsp;2014&nbsp;06:08:13&nbsp;GMT</td><td align="right">8210</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icon/file.ico" alt="[FILE]"></td><td><a href="/namespace/media/levels-sync.xml">levels&#x2d;sync&#x2e;xml</a></td><td align="right">Sat,&nbsp;29&nbsp;Mar&nbsp;2014&nbsp;06:08:47&nbsp;GMT</td><td align="right">2203</td></tr>
```

First I tried:

```
cat sample.txt | sed -n ’s/(\/namespace\/media\/.*-sync.xml)/\1/p’
```

but that gives me: ｀sed: -e expression #1, char 40: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS｀

Then I did:

```
cat sample.txt | sed -n 's/\(\/namespace\/media\/.*-sync.xml\)/\1/p'
```

But that just seems to return the entire file back to me.

My desired result is to get back

```
/namespace/media/nab-sync.xml
/namespace/media/levels-sync.xml
```

Any sed ninjas out there that can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct `sed` command based on your particular input:

```
cat sample.txt | sed 's/.*\(\/namespace\/media\/.*-sync.xml\).*/\1/g'
```

In sed, the groups are captured in between `\(...\)` but you were using `(...)`

Also, I have added `.*` add the both end of your original regex to discard all other texts.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

This `gnu awk` will find the correct data on any location on the line.
Its not `sed`, but for this `awk` may be better, or simpler to understand.

```
awk -v RS='href="' -F\" 'NR>1 {print $1}' file
/namespace/media/cloud-sync.xml
/namespace/media/levels-sync.xml
```

---

This `awk` should work on any system:

```
awk -F\" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~"href=") print $(i+1)}' file
/namespace/media/cloud-sync.xml
/namespace/media/levels-sync.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use gnu grep

```
grep -Po 'href="\K[^"]*' file

/namespace/media/cloud-sync.xml
/namespace/media/levels-sync.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*href="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' file
```

Look for `href` and extract the string between the next pair of double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

this will do it for the moment :

```
cat sample.txt | awk -F'["]' '{print $8}'
```

i am not quite familiar with sed so i am posting an awk response.

Comment: You could change the Filed Separator to `-F\"`  This solution will break if data are on other location on the line. I did not give you minus.  If people do that, they should tell why.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with awk but yes this is exactly the result I'm looking for. Could you help me understand what this is doing?

Comment: @JasonPerr -F is field separator it is used to break fields on the characters supplied. Here I have given `"` so it breaks it and I take the 8th piece of the field to print it.